# How to upgrade a VB6 app with .NET components

Tags: .net, vb6, interop

I want to make a change to a VB6 app which consists of a .EXE, no VB6 DLLs but a handful of .NET DLLs.

The interop is achieved by a one of the .NET dlls being referenced by the VB6 app which seems to require REGASM-ing of an associated .tlb file.

If I want to change only the VB6 app .exe, could I just compile it and drop it into the app folder on existing installations or are there going to be binding issues?

Comment: If tlb file is referenced from VB6 project, then that should work. IMHO this is kind of question, when quickest answer can be found by just trial and error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you regasm using this approach be sure to Use /codebase so that the application can live in the same folder as the DLL(s).

As a side note you may wish to actually specify the DispID of your methods on your Dll's so that if you change your Dll you won't need to change your application (which only really is a problem if you cause Alphabetic reordering of method names) by adding a new Method.

Comment: Does DispID allow you to recompile the DLL but not have to change the .tlb file?  How does it work?

Comment: That's correct, you'll need to setup an Interface explicitly, but yes you can alter your DLL (internal implementation, not method signatures) without needing to recompile your VB6 application as the TLB will not changed. I have an [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851501/handling-vb-net-events-in-vb6-code/1010085#1010085) that I answered sometime ago.