# How to have .NET component fire event in VB6 app?

Tags: .net, vb6, com-interop

I have a VB6 app which references and invokes a .NET GUI component.  The .NET GUI component has a datagrid.  I want a double-click on a row in the data-grid to cause a form in the VB6 app to show?

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: You should be able to do this easily by declaring your VB.NET component using the `WithEvents` keyword in VB 6. More information is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851501/handling-vb-net-events-in-vb6-code).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're accessing the .NET objects via COM interop, in which case you just create a normal event in the control and you can pick up on that in the consumer (VB6) as you do any other control events.

```
public MyNetClass {
  public delegate void RowDoubleClickedDelegate(int Row);

  public event RowDoubleClickedDelegate RowDoubleClicked;

  protected void OnRowDoubleClicked(int row) {
    if (RowDoubleClicked != null) {
      RowDoubleClicked(row);
    }
  }
}
```

And in VB6:

```
Dim WithEvents NetObect As MyNetClass

Private Sub MyNetClass_RowDoubleClicked(ByVal Row As Long)
  MsgBox CStr(Row) & " clicked"
End Sub
```

Comment: it's not a user control, it's a .NET DLL that displays a form.

Comment: And how is the VB6 app talking to the .NET library? If via COM interop, the same still applies, but you need to use `WithEvents` on the declaration as Cody suggested.

Comment: It is via COM interop. I still don't understand - if I'm inside a method in C# what code do I write to fire the VB6 event?

Comment: `this.eventname(value1);` See [this tutorial on the basics of .NET events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx). These events are then automatically made available to the consuming object via COM interop.

Comment: What happens if the .NET DLL handles the event as well.  Which code will be fired, or will it be both?

Comment: Both .NET and COM allow for multiple subscribers to the event (in .net) or event interface (in COM) so all subscribers will be called when the event fires. It is possible to override this but it's not particularly simple.

Comment: Can I consume one of the standard Winforms events such as `DataGridView_CellMouseDoubleClick` in the VB6 app, or do I have to declare a new event for this purpose?

Comment: @CJ7 Assuming that's an event of the COM object itself, yes. If it's a constituant control, then you'll need to handle it and pass it through.